# Wiremock query parameter JSON stub file

Tags: java, stub, wiremock

I'm trying to mock query parameter using a wiremock JSON stub file.

It works when I do it this way :

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/posts?id=1",
  },
//...
}
```

However when I change my query parameter to use the dedicated field like this it doesn't work anymore :

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPath": "/posts",
    "queryParameters": {
      "id": {
        "equalTo": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  //...
}
```

Any idea why ?

The test request looks like http://some-host/posts?id=1

Comment: below code works for you?

Comment: It doesn't, which version are you using ?

Comment: 2.18.0, are you getting any error?

Comment: Not really, I got an error saying "No further request expected", like when the mock is not called. I tried upgrading without result. I should try to produce a minimal reproductible exemple

Comment: are you doing it standalone? can you try http://localhost:8080/__admin? do you have this in mappings directory ?

Answer (score 16):

This works for me, change your `"urlPath"` to `"urlPathPattern"` but be careful in structuring this `JSON`. so `urlPath` is exact matching pattern, but `urlPathPattern` is regex matching on path and query parameter

```
  {
        "request": {
            "urlPathPattern": "/posts",
            "method": "GET",
            "queryParameters": {
                "id": {
                    "equalTo": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        "response": {
            "status": 200,
            "body":"This is successful"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Had the same issue. Changing it to urlPathPattern worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can try with **`urlPathPattern`** instead of **`urlPath`**.

As said by [here](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/385) urlPath which is for an exact match, and urlPathPattern is for **`regex`**.

So using **`urlPathPattern`** in QueryParameter your query get resolve.

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/posts",
    "queryParameters": {
      "id": {
        "equalTo": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  //...
}
```

Try and understand below concept for [Wiremock](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wiremock/info).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `urlPath` doesn't work with `queryParameters` and that this is simply expected behavior. :-/ I found [this Q&A on the topic](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/325) at the Wiremock Github repo. According to [@tomakehurst](https://github.com/tomakehurst)'s answer, this is expected behavior and `queryParameters` will match if you use `urlPathPattern`.

Comment: The link you provided says urlPattern doesn't work with queryParameters, not urlPath